# Using git-svn from within netbeans

Tags: netbeans, git-svn

Is there any way to use git-svn from within Netbeans. I'm currently working on a project that uses svn, and I'd like to at least use git locally.

Answer (score 6):

NetBeans currently [does not support git-svn](http://www.mentby.com/Group/netbeans/netbeans-git-support-git-svn.html). You still may use NetBeans for local Git repository, but you have to run `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit` yourself.

Another option is to use [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) on a server-side:

1. Install SubGit into your Subversion repository, see [documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/).
2. Setup remote access to created Git repository, e.g. using [git-http-backend](http://subgit.com/documentation/svn2git.html).
3. After that you may clone that Git repository via NetBeans and work with it as with usual Git repository.
4. On every push SubGit automatically converts your Git commits into Subversion revisions.
5. When someone commits changes to your Subversion repository, SubGit automatically converts them into new Git commits. So, you get them with a normal pull.

Hope that helps.